# Python typehinting class decorator

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, pylance

I am trying to implement the equivalent of the `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator for classes. When I researched this topic, it became apparent that I was not the first needing these and used the approach from https://discuss.python.org/t/yield-based-contextmanager-for-classes/8453.

Here is the implementation, with my attempt to add typehinting, unfortunately it breaks autocompletions: pylance does not know what `__enter__()` returns, and thinks that an internal class of the decorated class becomes a function. I.e. `with Example() as e: e.<autocomplete>` brings no joy.

```
from __future__ import annotations

import contextlib
from typing import Iterator, Protocol, Type, TypeVar, cast

# based on https://discuss.python.org/t/yield-based-contextmanager-for-classes/8453

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)
D = TypeVar("D", covariant=True)


class ClassYieldContextmanagerProtocol(Protocol[T, D]):
    def __contextmanager__(self: D) -> Iterator[T]:
        ...


class ClassYieldContextmanagerTransformedProtocol(Protocol[T, D]):
    def __contextmanager__(self: D) -> Iterator[T]:
        ...

    def __enter__(self: D) -> T:
        ...

    def __exit__(self: D, e_type, e, tb) -> T:
        ...


C = TypeVar("C", bound=ClassYieldContextmanagerProtocol, covariant=True)


# def contextmanager(
#     cls: Type[C[T]],
# ) -> Type[C[T]]:
# def contextmanager(
#     cls: Type[C],
# ) -> Type[C]:
def contextmanager(
    cls: Type[ClassYieldContextmanagerProtocol[T, D]],
) -> Type[ClassYieldContextmanagerTransformedProtocol[T, D]]:
    """Yield-based contextmanager."""
    contextmanager: contextlib.AbstractContextManager[T]  # | None = None  # check this

    def __enter__(self: D) -> T:  # noqa: N807 intend to declare magic method
        nonlocal contextmanager
        contextmanager = self.__contextmanager__()
        return contextmanager.__enter__()

    def __exit__(  # noqa: N807 intend to declare magic method
        self: D, exc_type, exc_value, traceback
    ) -> bool | None:
        return contextmanager.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)

    cls = cast(Type[ClassYieldContextmanagerTransformedProtocol[T, D]], cls)
    cls.__enter__ = __enter__  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    cls.__contextmanager__ = contextlib.contextmanager(cls.__contextmanager__)  # type: ignore[assignment]
    cls.__exit__ = __exit__  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    return cls


@contextmanager
class Example:
    def open(self):
        ...

    def close(self):
        ...

    class Internal:
        def __init__(self, parent: Example):
            self._parent = parent

        def operation(self):
            pass

    def __contextmanager__(self) -> Iterator[Example.Internal]:
        self.open()
        yield Example.Internal(self)
        self.close()


Example.Internal # Pylance shows me that Internal is a function here

with Example() as e:
    x = e # pylance infers x: Any instead of Example.Internal
```

In the code above I had various attempts at typehinting:

1. Specify only `ClassYieldContextmanagerProtocol`, with a single parameter.
   mypy tells me, that I do not match the protocl, since `self` is of a different type

```
playground.py:57: error: Argument 1 to "contextmanager" has incompatible type "type[Example]"; expected "ClassYieldContextmanagerProtocol[Internal]"  [arg-type]
playground.py:57: note: Following member(s) of "Example" have conflicts:
playground.py:57: note:     Expected:
playground.py:57: note:         def __contextmanager__() -> Iterator[Internal]
playground.py:57: note:     Got:
playground.py:57: note:         def __contextmanager__(self: Example) -> Iterator[Internal]
```

2. Use a  bound `TypeVar C`.
   I am not sure how to bind T now, so that T has the type which is returned by `__contextmanager__` and should be returned by `__enter__`
3. Add a second `TypeVar D` for the `ClassYieldContextmanagerProtocol` to make the type of self generic.
   Now it is impossible to work with the type vars, the Protocol expects covariance, but when used as a parameter that is not allowed.

   ```
   playground.py:43: error: Cannot use a covariant type variable as a parameter  [misc]
   playground.py:45: error: "D" has no attribute "__contextmanager__"  [attr-defined]
   playground.py:49: error: Cannot use a covariant type variable as a parameter  [misc]
   playground.py:83: error: "Example" has no attribute "__enter__"  [attr-defined]
   playground.py:83: error: "Example" has no attribute "__exit__"  [attr-defined]
   ```

### Summary

How can I typehint the class-`contextmanager` decorator [1] so that autocompletion with pylance does not break? (Bonus points if it works for mypy to, since that is used for typechecking, but the developer convenience of keeping autocompletion is paramount).

While an alternative implementation as an inheritable class might be possible, I would prefer the decorator model. (And learning how to tell mypy that `attr-define` is ok in a class decorator).

[1] I guess I should rename it to avoid confusion with contextlib.contextmanager, but I do not want to regenerate all the error messages

Comment: The typing system doesn't support class decorators very well (due to lack of support for [intersection types](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213)), so I would avoid class decorators and stick to inheritance. That, or ditch pylance and use [VSCode-mypy](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mypy) as the type checker for VSCode's intellisense ([coming soon!](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mypy/issues/37)), and start developing your own mypy plugin for your `@contextmanager` decorator.